# Broad cast message to specific page using signalr

Tags: asp.net, signalr

suppose i have forum where people post their question and another people post the answer. say for example person A post a question "What is signalr ?" and stand at that page. other person also open that page for answering. if other person post any answer then i want that that answer will be shown in that page open by other users. suppose five user open that page and one of them answer then five user will see that answer.

normally when we like to broadcast any message to all then we use syntax like at server end

```
Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);
```

so according to my above situation what kind of syntax i need to use?

here are few guide i found for broad cast message type and those are follows

```
// Call send on everyone
        Clients.All.send(message);

        // Call send on everyone except the caller
        Clients.Others.send(message);

        // Call send on everyone except the specified connection ids
        Clients.AllExcept(Context.ConnectionId).send(message);

        // Call send on the caller
        Clients.Caller.send(message);

        // Call send on everyone in group "foo"
        Clients.Group("foo").send(message);

        // Call send on everyone else but the caller in group "foo"
        Clients.OthersInGroup("foo").send(message);

        // Call send on everyone in "foo" excluding the specified connection ids
        Clients.Group("foo", Context.ConnectionId).send(message);

        // Call send on to a specific connection
        Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).send(message);
```

which one i need to use ? please explain & thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a div on the page that has an id of the question. So you would have something like:

```
<div id="theAskedQuestionId"><!-- the answer will be inserted here--></div>
```

so for example:

```
<div id="12345"><!-- the answer will be inserted here--></div>
```

And then you can use jquery to inject the answer into the div. An example of this is:

```
var messagePublisher = $.connection.yourHubName;

messagePublisher.client.broadcastMessage = function(divId, message){
$(divId).html(message); //note: divId will be something like #12345
};
```

This will allow you to only show the message to the users that are looking at the specific question instead of broadcasting the message to users looking at any question. I think this is what you were asking for help on.